# Can a professor / institution drop absent/non-contributing students from a course (any known precedent)?

Tags: teaching

In the scope of undergraduate college courses, is there any known precedent of being able to drop students from the course due to excessive absences without reason, lack of any real contribution, or little to no performance?

For example, something like:

> Notice: given your grade of 35% you are at risk of being dropped from the course, you have 2 weeks to make a passing grade.

Comment: In the US this is a local question dependent on university rules. I doubt that it is commonly permitted, but you have to ask locally. Other places there might be national rules that apply.

Comment: "Poor performance" and "disruption" are different things. I had a colleague with a student who got quite threatening and scary. That is different than dropping someone for failing.

Comment: How would one know, a priori, who is 'highly interested' and will remain 'highly interested' once in the course? "Sounds cool! Wait, I have to do hard work???"

Comment: As noted above, I think this question should be split in two. Poor performance and disruption are different and should get different answers.

Comment: In this case I think I intended "poor perf & disruptive", last year had a low perf student drag class culture down. In theory it seems more quantifiable to drop a stop for a quantitative grade rather than "disruptive". I'll rescope it there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is offensive in equiparating poor-performing students to disruptive of the class. This is a dictorial-style thinking

Comment: @EarlGrey looks like that remark was added by another editor, I have removed it

Comment: Actually, I copied-and-pasted that remark from your comment above. As it is, your question is very vague and has attracted several close votes; so, I suggest you add some rationale about why you would like to drop the poorly-performing students.

Comment: Yeah we need to close this... others are trying to fix the question and are just making it worse. I'm voting to close my own question :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not unusual for students to be required to attend class during the first week and to be administratively dropped if they don't but I think you're talking about something less clear cut than that.

In my experience, I've taught for schools with the following policies that I think address what you're asking:

- Students who are inactive for two weeks are administratively dropped regardless of their grade.
- Students who are inactive and can no longer numerically pass the class are dropped.
- Students who have a grade below passing at a fixed point in introductory math and English classes are dropped.

Comment: It's worth noting that a good search term for this policy is "administrative withdrawal," which is a process found in many university handbooks, at least in the US.

Comment: But those aren't "faculty decision" rules. And they are clearly spelled out to students in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your example simply won't work in many US institutions.  There are too many ramifications for the student (e.g., failure to reach full time student status, tuition dollars already paid,...)

The time to address this is before students enroll, by being very specific about prereq work.  The catch-all would be "instructor permission required" as a prerequisite.

For the example you describe, the correct course of action is to let the student know they're at risk of failing the course... period. This lets the student determine if there is a mechanism to safely dropping the course.  If the student doesn't drop, and does not merit a passing grade, at the end of the semester, you simply issue a failing grade.

As an aside, if you're providing adequate feedback as the course progresses, the student should be aware that they're at risk of failing without such a notice.

Comment: I don't see prerequisites mentioned in the question; I don't think it is fair to assume that the cause of the students' performance is due to lacking prior foundational instruction based on the information provided, nor is it clear that anything could have necessarily been predicted ahead of time about the student's performance, the question is about whether this is an option once the student is present in the class and does not seem likely to be able to achieve a passing grade.

Comment: @BryanKrause  The original question asked about advice to make sure only appropriate students enrolled in the class, and this was partially responsive to that.

Answer (score 1):

Most often this is done via prerequisites being enforced.  Generally, in such a course you will need to have received at least a "C" in the prerequisite classes or you will not be allowed to register for such a course or you will be de-registered before the term start (in the case where you enroll in the next course in a sequence in consecutive semesters).

Generally it would be unethical for a professor at a university to outright drop you from a course.  However, you can ask them advice based on your background and they can give feedback as to whether their course might be appropriate given your background.  In institutions like mine where classes can be as big as 200+ students it is almost a given that at least 1 student will fail the class, so professors and instructors generally are not as worried about this.

Comment: I don't see prerequisites mentioned in the question; I don't think it is fair to assume that the cause of the students' performance is due to lacking prior foundational instruction based on the information provided.

Comment: I'm saying that from my experience, this is the only way where students can be dropped from a course other than them doing so on their own.  Instructors _may_ be allowed to waive prerequisites and allow a student entry into their class but institutions and departments have set rules on what instructors are allowed to do so it depends on such factors.